# Grouped notifications count (+1) like Gmail

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I already grouped my notifications, but I can't figure out how to add such red number **+1**, which indicates remaining notifications. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: this is OS and device driven. on my pixel, it looks exactly like that image you shown. on my note 8 it the number is at the top of the row.

Answer (score 1):

The style of the displayed notifications depends on the device.

- on Nexus 5X, it shows up to 5 lines and **+3** number.
- tested also on Samsung Galaxy S8 - shows up to 2 lines and number on top of notification.

---

## Nexus 5X

[image: Grouped notifications]